# summarise with dplyr and a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- read.table(text = "group  age status
A   25  yes
A   32  no
A   58  yes
A   78  no
A   76  yes
B   21  no
B   71  yes
B   43  no
B   48  no
C   39  no
C   82  yes
C   87  no
C   91  yes", header = T)
```

I want to group_by group column and then summarise in a way where if the age is less than 50 and status is "yes", count those values and then count total number of values for which age is less than 50.
So for 'A' in the data frame:

```
age_lt_50_yes = 1
age_lt_50 = 2
```

Similarly for age greater than 50 with yes and then age greater than 50;
For 'A'; this will be :

```
age_gt_50_yes = 2
age_gt_50 = 3
```

I actually want to have a ratio of age_lt_50_yes/age_lt_50 and for 'A' this will be 1/2 and for age_gt_50_yes/age_gt_50 = 2/3 for 'A'

If by any means I land into a situation where I have something like this 0/0; then just want 0 as an output.

How can I do this using dplyr?

Here is what I have tried:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(age_le50_prop = sum(age <= 50) / n(),
            age_gt50_prop = sum(age > 50) / n())
```

I need to add status in the summarize function

My output should be like this:

```
group_by age_lt_50  age_gr_50
A   0.5 0.66
B   0   1
C   0   0.66
```

Comment: Good effort on giving us sample data, though please try it yourself: for me, `sep="\t"` causes it to be a single column. Removing that provides usable data, I'll suggest an edit to the question momentarily.

Comment: `... %>% group_by(group, age > 50) %>% ...`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"add status in the summarize function"*. I've tried various applications of adding `status == "yes"` on both sides of the `/` without matching your expected output.

Comment: What I meant is that I will have to use status == "yes" in the summarise command, but not sure how to use it. If you look at just A, age_lt_50 has 1 yes and total counts for age < 50 is 2, so the ratio is 1/2 or 0.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `reframe()`, and simply define the counts you need. The final line will take care of the case where you had 0/0

```
reframe(
  df, 
  age_lt_50 = sum(age<50 & status=="yes")/sum(age<50),
  age_gt_50 = sum(age>=50 & status=="yes")/sum(age>=50),
  .by=group) %>% replace(is.na(.),0)
```

Output:

```
  group age_lt_50 age_gt_50
1     A       0.5 0.6666667
2     B       0.0 1.0000000
3     C       0.0 0.6666667
```

Here is an alternative that demos the use of `summarize()` instead of reframe, and (independently) also demonstrates another way to check for that possibility of 0 in the denominator:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(
    age_lt_50 = {if(sum(age<50)==0) 0 else sum(age<50 & status=="yes")/sum(age<50)},
    age_gt_50 = {if(sum(age>=50)==0) 0 else sum(age>=50 & status=="yes")/sum(age>=50)}
)
```

Comment: it is checking the result from `reframe()` (i.e. the resulting data frame) for values that are `NA`, which could arise from 0/0, and replacing with 0 (which I understand you requested in the original post); I've added an option that demonstrate the use of summarize, along with alternative way of checking for that 0 in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks for the second solution. In this solution, do we need curly braces `{` `}` ? Solution works without them as well

Comment: I guess just user preference.. The idea is that the expression could get quite complicated (say, in some other scenario), and it might be good to wrap in `{...}`.. On the other hand, one could argue that if it got so complicated that `{...}` was needed, then it is probably better to move it off into a small helper function.. You are right that in this case it is simple enough to not need.